# Efficient lookup between pandas column values and a list of values

Tags: python, pandas, search, lookup

I have a list of n elements lets say:

```
[5,30,60,180,240]
```

And a dataframe with the following characteristics

```
id1 id2 feat1
1     1   40
1     2   40
1     3   40
1     4   40
2     6   87
2     7   87
2     8   87
```

The combination of id1 + id2 is unique but all of the records with common id1 share the value of feat1. I would like to write a function to run it via groupby + apply (or whatever is faster) that creates a column called 'closest_number'. The 'closest_number' will be the closest element between the feat1 column for a given id1+id2 (or id1 as the records share feat1) and each of the elements of the list.

Desired output:

```
id1 id2 feat1 closest_number
1     1   40      30
1     2   40      30
1     3   40      30
1     4   40      30
2     6   87      60
2     7   87      60
2     8   87      60
```

If this will be a standard 2 array lookup problem I could do:

```
def get_closest(array, values):
    # make sure array is a numpy array
    array = np.array(array)

    # get insert positions
    idxs = np.searchsorted(array, values, side="left")
    
    # find indexes where previous index is closer
    prev_idx_is_less = ((idxs == len(array))|(np.fabs(values - array[np.maximum(idxs-1, 0)]) < np.fabs(values - array[np.minimum(idxs, len(array)-1)])))
    idxs[prev_idx_is_less] -= 1
    
    return array[idxs]
```

An if I apply this do the columns there I will get as output:

```
array([30, 60])
```

However I will not get any information about which indexes they have the correspondence with 30 and 60.

What will be the optimum way of doing this? As my list of elements is very small I have created distance columns in my dataset and then I have selected the one that gets me the min distances.

But I assume there should be a more elegant way of doing this.

BR
E

Comment: Do you *have* to use numpy? There are a lot of simple using vanilla python for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_closest` as follows:

```
# obtain the series with index id1 and values feat1
vals = df.groupby("id1")["feat1"].first().rename("closest_number")

# find the closest values and assign them back
vals[:] = get_closest(s, vals)

# merge the series into the original DataFrame
res = df.merge(vals, right_index=True, left_on="id1", how="left")

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
   id1  id2  feat1  closest_number
0    1    1     40              30
1    1    2     40              30
2    1    3     40              30
3    1    4     40              30
4    2    6     87              60
5    2    7     87              60
6    2    8     87              60
```

Comment: Hi Dani, this works but unfortunately when my closest number vector is 30,90 (for instance) and the feat value is 88 it is returning 30 as the closest. Is this due to the np.searchsorted(side='left') or I am doing something wrong?.